# STOC Onboard Processing

Tags: calibration, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My colleague and I are attempting to use a Videre Design STOC Stereovision 30cm camera, but we're having some problems with the onboard processing. When using offboard processing we get good data, but the data we're getting back is worthless when we use the camera's onboard processing. It seems possible that our calibration parameters aren't being properly uploaded to the camera's onboard processor, but we can't confirm this.

Has anybody encountered a similar problem using Videre hardware? Their support hasn't been much help to us, so we're at something of a dead end unless we can find someone else out there who might have some useful experience with this hardware.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10605/stoc-onboard-processing/) by [llewellyn](https://answers.ros.org/users/837/llewellyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-14**:
Could you update your question to include which ROS driver (and version of it) you are using (as well as any other relevant things such as OS, ROS distro, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0